# Why when we put 2 divs with display inline-block and box-sizing: border-box a white space is rendered when borders are different?

Tags: html, css

please consider this code, why d3 and d4 are not aligned ?
what is the white space on top of d4 ?

```css
.myContainer {
  display: block;
}

#d3 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 5px solid #aef704;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}

#d4 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid #aef704;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: brown;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="myContainer">
    <div id="d3">test content d3</div>
    <div id="d4">test content d4</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

those 2 divs should both rendered inline-block and should have 150px width and 150px height, then why the second one is a little bit lower than the first one.
here is what rendered :
[image: white space on second div]

Comment: Using a white-space, tab or enter between 2 `inline-block` items without flexbox will result in a gap between the items.

Answer (score 0):

Because the default [vertical alignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) for inline elements is baseline. Change it easily by setting it to something like top instead.

```css
.myContainer {
  display: block;
}

#d3 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 5px solid #aef704;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}

#d4 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid #aef704;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: brown;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}

#d3,
#d4 {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="myContainer">
  <div id="d3">test content d3</div>
  <div id="d4">test content d4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use flex which is more robust. See usage here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.myContainer {
  display: flex;
}

#d3 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 5px solid #aef704;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}

#d4 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid #aef704;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: brown;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="myContainer">
  <div id="d3">test content d3</div>
  <div id="d4">test content d4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

add this to your main container holding the two divs.

```
.myContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-item: center;
}
```